# Elementary set theory and singletons. Valid mathematical reasoning?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I want to show that:

$$x=y \iff x \in \{y\}$$
$$x=y \iff y \in \{x\}$$
$$x=y \iff \{x\} = \{y\}$$

I wonder if this is mathematically correct:

By definition, $$z\in\{z\}$$

If $x=y$ then $x \in \{y\}$, by switching the variables (in the definition). And if $x \in \{y\}$, then $x=y$ since the set have only one elementent ant therefore must equal $x$. So $x=y \iff x \in \{y\}$.

$x=y \iff y \in \{x\}$ follows from symmetry. This is just the same as the first.

We know that $\{x\}=\{x\}$, so if $x=y$ then $\{x\}=\{y\}$. If $\{x\}=\{y\}$ then $x=y$ since the sets have only one element each and therefore the elements must be equal. Hence $x=y \iff \{x\} = \{y\}$.

Comment: Sounds right to me.

Comment: Thanks! I guess it is.